# shdocvw opens browser with two IE tabs using C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I have a very simple method in my code that I use to open an IE browser, version IE 11.

```
    private void btOpenIEOnly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();
        ie.Navigate2("www.google.com", 1);
    }
```

Every time I click the button the IE browser opens, but I get two tabs.  The first tab is a blank tab, no name on it, body is blank.

My IE settings that I believe are relevant based on researching other questions here on stackoverflow:

1. Home page set to Google...there are no extra lines in the box
2. "When a new tab is opened, open" - set to "The new tab page"
3. "Open links from other programs in:" - set to "A new tab in the current 
    window.
4. Pop blocker is off

I have tried this snippet on Win7 and Win10.

Can you advise what I am missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: "Every time I click the button" which button?

Comment: The btnOpenIEOnly button which triggers the click event.  I certainly failed to mention that.  My form has a button that triggers the event, not method, noted above.

Comment: Try this- ie.Navigate2("www.google.com", 3);

Comment: Thanks Souvik.  I updated the snippet as noted and I see the same behavior.  Incidentally, I have tried several of the BrowserNavConstant enumerations with no success.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Selenium in C#. It is much easier, gives more control and have a good documentation and support.